# Must upload one dSYM file is always showing in Firebase Crashlytics

Tags: firebase, crashlytics, dsym

I am developing a react native app and I am using Firebase Crashlytics. On my Crashlytics "dashboard" is showing that I must upload a dSYM file when the selected platform is IOS. I already followed the steps that Firebase suggests (after that is shown in my terminal the message "Successfully uploaded Crashlytics symbols") and tried different suggestions from another questions, but the warning is still there. I have seen some people saying that it could take 24 hours, but I am trying to resolve this for two days

Hope you can help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Firebaser here - I recommend starting here and going through the whole doc to try out all the listed suggestions: https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-deobfuscated-reports?platform=ios.

In general, "Successfully uploaded Crashlytics symbols" only means that the execution of the terminal command and the submission of whichever files you picked was successful, not necessarily that the correct dSYMs were uploaded. To check if the dSYMs you uploaded were the ones that were missing in the Crashlytics console, you can run the following command and compare the output to the missing dSYMs tab:

`dwarfdump -u /path/to/dSYM`

If the dSYMs aren't the correct ones, you may want to check where you're downloading them from. If you've only tried your local Xcode archives, try downloading from App Store Connect (if the app has been registered with the App Store).

Otherwise, you can try this command to find any downloaded/archived dSYMs that match the ones from your missing dSYMs tab on Firebase:

`mdfind -name .dSYM | while read -r line; do dwarfdump -u "$line"; done`

Comment: Hello!!

First of all, thank you for answer my question.

I already tried all the steps recommended on that link and I downloaded from App Store Connect the correct .dSYM. When I submit the command line on terminal, it also sends me with that "success" message, a text saying that I submitted the dSYM file and the name of that file is the same that is presented in the warning from Firebase Console.

I really can't understand what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Hmm, that definitely sounds strange. I think support would need to dig more into your project to understand what's going on, it could be specific to your app or some sort of backend issue. Could you reach out to Firebase support with a description of your issue, what you've tried so far, and a link to this stackoverflow post? https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/contact

Comment: If it's a general issue, I can update my answer here to include what worked for you :)

Comment: I contacted support and now I am waiting for their answer. I'll keep in touch.